# Explaining large sum transfer not consistent with monthly earnings

Tags: uk, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, nigerian-citizens

I am applying for a standard visitors UK visa this week. I have a good monthly income and stable employment. I had my brother in-law transfer a sum of money through my bank account to my mother (almost double my monthly income) two months ago, which I forwarded same day to her account and it's all reflected in my bank statement. I want to know if I need to explain this to the consular since the sum is not consistent with my monthly income.
Thanks

Comment: If your mother has her own bank account, why did the funds need to come through yours instead of direct to her? Yes, I’d explain the transaction in your application.